# Show IPAD numeric keypad on Zend Form element

Tags: ipad, zend-framework, input, numeric

In html elements if we use type="number" for input field, IPAD will show numeric keypad by default for that field.

But in Zend when I use CreateElement('number', 'zipcode'); It shows an error. Is there any other way to show numeric keypad on zend element when using IPAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write custom form element, e.g. `My_Form_Element_Number` that extends `Zend_Form_Element_Text` and custom view helper, e.g. `My_Viev_Helper_Number` to display it with proper attributes.

**UPDATE**: example (not fully working, just to give an idea)

```
// custom form element
class My_Form_Element_Number extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml
{
    /**
     * Use formIframe view helper 
     */
    public $helper = 'formNumber';
}

// custom view helper based on Zend_View_Helper_FormText
class My_View_Helper_FormNumber extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement
{
    $xhtml = '<input type="number"'
            . ' name="' . $this->view->escape($name) . '"'
            . ' id="' . $this->view->escape($id) . '"'
            . ' value="' . $this->view->escape($value) . '"'
            . $disabled
            . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs)
            . $endTag;

    return $xhtml;
}

// usage
$element = new My_Form_Element_Number('fieldname');
```